# Resizing existing pdfpage not top centered

Tags: pdf, resize, pdfsharp

All,

I am trying to resize an existing PDF file but the result is not centered, what am I doing wrong? I am using PDFsharp, please see below code:

```
Private Sub ResizePDF(sourcePDF As String, outPDF As String)
    Dim form As XPdfForm = XPdfForm.FromFile(sourcePDF)
    Dim doc2 As New PdfSharp.Pdf.PdfDocument()
    doc2.Options.CompressContentStreams = True
    doc2.Options.ColorMode = PdfSharp.Pdf.PdfColorMode.Rgb
    For pagenumber As Integer = 1 To (form.PageCount + 1) - 1
        Dim page As PdfSharp.Pdf.PdfPage = doc2.Pages.Add()
        form.PageNumber = pagenumber
        page.Width = form.PixelWidth + 15.36
        page.Height = form.PixelHeight + 40.32
        Dim graph As XGraphics = XGraphics.FromPdfPage(page)
        Dim rect As New XRect(0, 0, page.Width, page.Height)
        graph.DrawImage(form, rect)
    Next
    If IO.Directory.Exists(IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(outPDF)) = False Then IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(outPDF))
    doc2.Save(outPDF)
End Sub
```

Input file: https://www.dropbox.com/s/po87x8c44r90py2/HFD_20151007_0_001_061.pdf?dl=0

Ouput File: https://www.dropbox.com/s/pt5pcyfayri6ory/HFD_20151007_0_001_061_output.pdf?dl=0

Answer (score 0):

We have a workaround for you: Instead of calling `graph.DrawImage(form, rect)` please call
`graph.DrawImage(form, rect.X - form.Page.MediaBox.X1, rect.Y + form.Page.MediaBox.Y1, rect.Width, rect.Height)`.
I'm not sure if this is valid VB.NET, but it works in C# and should work for VB.NET with little or no changes.

This is a workaround needed for PDFsharp 1.50 beta 2 and all earlier versions.

When switching to PDFsharp 1.50 beta 3 or a later version (not yet available), you will have to use the initial code `graph.DrawImage(form, rect)` again.